# Why is a gaussian fixed point called gaussian?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, terminology

I know what a gaussian fixed point is, and I did read the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_fixed_point), but it wasn't helpful. It says because the probability distribution is gaussian, but what probability distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability distribution of *any* observable that is a linear function of fields is Gaussian i.e. 
$$A\exp(-(x-x_0)^2/2\Delta x^2)$$ in the ground state of a Gaussian fixed point. Also, the path integral of a Gaussian fixed point (free field theory) is the integral of the exponential of a bilinear function of the fields which is *also* called Gaussian.